# How to Move Products, Attributes, Images, and Customers From One Magento Installation to Another

Tags: magento-1.9, database, import, export, importexport

I have Magento 1.9.2.1 installed and I also installed a test Magento installation in a subdomain. Basically, the theme I have installed on my current Magento installation was designed for an older version of Magento. I installed a new responsive theme designed for 1.9.x installed on the test Magento installation. Note that both Magento installations are 1.9.2.1.

I need to copy all products along with images and attributes from the current Magento installation to the test installation. I would like to be able to copy the customers as well, but it's not completely necessary. How can I do this? Any and all details would be appreciated. I've tried various ways with the Export/Import Data Profiles and keep getting errors (image not present, etc.)

My goal is to copy all products, images, attributes and possibly customers to the test site. Then, remove the original installation and move the test site to take it's place. My old theme on the original installation is very integrated into the files and almost impossible to remove. I needed to start fresh.

EDIT: I'm at my wits end on this. I cleared all logs in the database and exported it again. I uploaded it via FTP and against tried to import it to the new database via SSH and I get this exact error: `ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 22349: Duplicate entry '3-13-70-0' for key '479DA1DD8CED295B97C96AEF816CA4EE'`

I also was able to export the database into a gzip file and attempt to import it via phpMyAdmin. I get the same error..
[image]

Comment: You can just dump the DB and load it in the new server then copy over the media folder from one server to the other.

/Edit: and some helpful links: https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_move.htm http://inchoo.net/magento/moving-magento-store-to-another-server/

Comment: I tried that but my database is apparently too large to upload. Plus, if I did actually get to do that, would I have to change any settings anywhere? Would it mess anything up with the new installation on my test domain?

Comment: You can play with [mysqldump options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) to get a chunked dump; a set of options that worked for me in the past are: `mysqldump -u$USER -h$HOST --extended-insert --net_buffer_length=5000 --quick $DB -p$PASS`. After importing the DB you'll only have to change the `'web/%secure/base_url'` values from `core_config_data` and `'%/cookie_domain'` to match your new URL and domain.

Comment: I just exported the database and uploaded it via ftp. I then used SSH to try to import the database. Now it's telling me I have duplicate entries (Error 1062)? I don't understand this. All of my products are unique. I don't understand how there would be a duplicate entry. Are there logs or anything I should clear or delete before exporting the database?

Comment: I'm at my wits end on this. I cleared all logs in the database and exported it again. I uploaded it via FTP and against tried to import it to the new database via SSH and I get this exact error:

ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 22349: Duplicate entry '3-13-70-0' for key '479DA1DD8CED295B97C96AEF816CA4EE'

Comment: have you tried dropping the imported database before reimporting it each time?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: On the server you want to import the database run the following: `DROP DATABASE $DB_NAME; CREATE DATABASE $DB_NAME;` This will remove the database with all it's tables and create a new empty one in which you can load the dump from production.

Comment: Since this is causing so much of a headache, I'm just weighing out all of my options. Is there a way I could just tell the test Magento installation to look at the production database instead of importing the production database into the test one?